# How can we decrypt the password in Croogo?

Tags: php, cakephp, croogo

I want to fetch user's password from database in Croogo,
tried

```
decrypt( string $cipher , string $key );

$result = Security::decrypt($cipher, $key);
```

but nothing works!!

Answer (score 2):

Passwords are hashed not encrypted. It's an irreversible process so you can't "decrypt" them.